# How to override all click handlers for an element type in the DOM using React?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I want to override the click handler for a elements.

So far, I managed to achieve this for my own code simply by wrapping my `<a>` elements in my own component, like this simplified example:

```
class Link extends React.Component {
  onClick(event) {
    // ...
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
    if (this.props.onClick)
      this.props.onClick(event);
  }

  render() {
    return <a href={this.props.href} onClick={(e) => this.onClick(e)}>{this.props.children}</a>
  }
}
```

Instead of using `<a href="...">`, I just use `<Link href="...">`

Unfortunately, I need to use other components that have links inside them. Is there any way I can be notified of any DOM change so that I can apply this handler? I'd rather not have to re-write the dependencies; is there any way to change how they render?

I thought about using a visitor pattern to recursively visit all the children of all components, but I realised this might not return the results I expect as the elements will only exist when they're actually rendered.

Comment: What is the behaviour that you expect when your link contains other <a> elements?

Comment: recursive - I want to change any `a` in the document

Comment: If you use react you are actually writing the elements, it is highly recommended to not modify the generated DOM. Why not just use <Link> instead <a> in your subcomponents ?

Comment: I didnt write the sub components. This is to save me from re-writing all those components that I depend on.

Comment: I'm coming to the conclusion that the correct way is to write a custom Renderer; there are plenty out there, but its not officially supported.